# Node-Red - Using MSG fields on JSONata expression

Tags: node-red, jsonata

I'm using Node-Red.
I have set a field named "counter" for msg object, I want to use it's value in an JSONata expression, the expression is this:

```
$keys(payload)[counter]
```

Consider this payload:

```
{
    "counter": 0,
    "payload": {"cv": 1, "fg": 2}
}
```

When I test it, I get this result:

[image]

When I enter 0 directly instead of using counter, it shows the correct result and when I just use "counter" as expression, it evaluate it as 0

[image]

[image]

Why the main expression is not evaluating correctly?

How should I write it?

Answer (score 1):

The expression you provided does not work, because the `counter` path gets executed against a local evaluation context, which is an entry of the `$keys(payload)` array: "cv" or "fg". So, `counter` gets evaluated as `"cv".counter` which is undefined.

To fix it, you can either reference the root document explicitly, to break out of the local evaluation context:

`$keys(payload)[$$.counter]`

Or, reassign the value of the `counter` to a variable, and use it inside the filtering expression:

```
(
  $counter := counter;
  $keys(payload)[$counter]
)
```

See both examples on the Stedi Playground:

- https://stedi.link/rcHF76X
- https://stedi.link/19eHBVO